# About the point $P$ inside a square $ABCD$ satisfying $BP = BC$ and $\angle APD = 90^\circ$

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve the following problem from the Polish *XI Olimpiada Matematyczna Gimnazjalistów*, question 2 from [this document](http://www.omg.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/1etap15.pdf). (The deadline of 12 October 2015 has now passed.)

[image]

I managed to solve it using analytical approach, but I have to solve it the "normal way" - in this case using angles.

I almost found the proof, but I need a help in showing 1 thing. Take a look at my approach, where I found almost all angles:

[image]

I don't know how to show, that angles $DCQ$ is equal to angle $PBC$. When we prove this, we'll prove, that $AP=2PD$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the circle $\Gamma_1$ centred at $B$ passing through $A, P, C$, and the circle $\Gamma_2$ through $A, D, P$.  Since $\angle DPA$ is a right angle, $AD$ is a diameter of $\Gamma_2$.  Therefore the radius of $\Gamma_1$ is twice that of $\Gamma_2$.

Using your angle chase, $AP$ subtends an angle of $180-2\alpha$ at the centre of $\Gamma_1$, and hence an angle of $90-\alpha$ at the circumference.  We also see that $DP$ subtends an angle of $90-\alpha$ at the circumference of $\Gamma_2$.  Hence the ratio of $AP$ to $DP$ is the ratio of the two radii, which is $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much once again! I understand it now clearly :).

Comment: You're welcome.  I like Brian's approach too; it's perhaps a bit simpler than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I would go about it a bit differently. If $Q$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AP}$, $\angle BQA$ is a right angle, $|BA|=|AD|$ (why?), and $\angle ABQ=\angle ADP$ (why?), so the triangles $\triangle ABQ$ and $\triangle ADP$ are congruent. Thus, $|AQ|=|DP|$, and therefore ... ?

Comment: Do you mean $|AQ|=|AP|$ or $|AQ|=|DP|$?

Comment: @Jennifer: I most certainly mean $|DP|$; thanks for catching it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your approach, I understand it as well. Unfortunately Stackexchange won't let me accept two answers.

Comment: @Jennifer: You’re welcome.